What frequencies can you freely speak on?
Are there any frequencies that you can use to communicate with your family at home when you are flying and for a wokie talkie I am wondering if there are just any frequencies that you can speak freely on to people on the ground please may someone help.
By the way I'm a halecopter pilot.

You can always get a Amateur Radio License, commonly referred to as HAM radio. There are quite a few private pilots who are HAM radio operators that take radios with them when flying.
There are even a few commercial pilots with HAM licenses that make contact while flying.

The operator of the ground station must also have an amateur license.
